# How to remove a setting imported by an auto plugin in sbt 1.2.8?

Tags: scala, sbt

An sbt plugin (https://github.com/iheartradio/play-swagger), adds its own task as a dependency to `run`, and overrides the `run` task,

```
override def projectSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(...,
  run := (run in Compile).dependsOn(swagger).evaluated
)
```

**How can I get rid of this setting when the plugin is loaded as an auto-plugin in sbt 1.2.8?**

I found ["Control over automatically added settings"](https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Community/ChangeSummary_0.13.0.html#control-over-automatically-added-settings), but it doesn't seem to be available in sbt  after 0.13.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve it is to set it back to its [original default](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/ae9bba4b80c334c66dba770631cadbd1cbba51f8/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L669):

```
run := sbt.Defaults.foregroundRunTask.evaluated
```

Comment: Cool, that might work! We also use Play, I think it might meddle with the `run` task as well :-/

Comment: Yes, you can also try to set it to the Play's default. Unfortunately, I don't know any way to "cancel" a setting from a given plugin. You could alternatively try to add `swagger in run := {}` to neutralize this modification of the `run` task.